# how to solve local wampserver windows 10 magento2.3.4 Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2.3.4

[image]

local wampserver windows 10 magento2.2 to 2.3 Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. and Your session has expired errors click addtocart,wishlist,subscribe buttons. magento2.3.4 error i try following below:

php.ini &.htaccess &users php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
    php_value max_input_vars 700000
    php_value memory_limit 5G
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
and catch clear and flush and 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
removed var/* pub/static/*

and setting cookies life time 3600 http only yes
please help 'Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page' solution

Comment: Hello @sreenu you go to your database and find `core_config_data` and add `web/unsecure/base_url` add `http://127.0.0.1/yourmagentoroot/` . And Second `web/secure/base_url` add `https://127.0.0.1/yourmagentoroot/` after run `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: i follow the below steps:
using new window and removed cache files . invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. error came
why this error came magento2.2 and 2.3 http://127.0.0.1/magento234/index.php/
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
remoed global file please help 'invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.' error solution thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Baseurl and Secute Baseurl to "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost", then flush your cache.

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/"
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://127.0.0.1/"
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: i used UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url'; and cache:flush but not solved invalid form key

Comment: Usually you should have a forward slash by the end of your base urls "/". I can see it in yours. Also, get sure you clean all your browser cache, or even better, use an incognito window.